# how to select rows with float64 nan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe from excel which has several NaNs in rows.I`d like to replace rows whose values are all NaNs by another baseline row.

The original dataframe is like this:

```
                    Country Name  Years  tariff1_1  tariff1_2  tariff1_3  
830                 Hungary       2004   9.540313   6.287314  13.098201   
831                 Hungary       2005   9.540789   6.281724  13.124401 
832                 Hungary       2006   NaN        NaN       NaN 
833                 Hungary       2007   NaN        NaN       NaN 
834                 eu            2005   8.55       5.7       11.4
835                 eu            2006   8.46       5.9       11.6
836                 eu            2007   8.56       5.3       11.9
```

so if the tariffs for Hungary of a specific year are all NaNs,this row should be replaced by the eu data, according to the exact year.

The ideal result is :

```
                    Country Name  Years  tariff1_1  tariff1_2  tariff1_3  
830                 Hungary       2004   9.540313   6.287314  13.098201   
831                 Hungary       2005   9.540789   6.281724  13.124401 
832                 Hungary       2006   8.46       5.9       11.6 
833                 Hungary       2007   8.56       5.3       11.9
834                 eu            2005   8.55       5.7       11.4
835                 eu            2006   8.46       5.9       11.6
836                 eu            2007   8.56       5.3       11.9
```

I looked into the type of the NaN in a specific row ('Hungary',2006) and it turns to be 'float64'.So it turns out as **ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''** after I use **`np.isnan`**.

So I adopted **`math.isnan`**. But **it doesn`t seem to detect the NaN** in my test row:

```
test=df.loc[(df['Country Name'] == 'Hungary') & (df['Years']== 2006)]

test.iloc[:,4]
Out[293]: 
832   NaN
Name: tariff1_3, dtype: float64

math.isnan(any(test))
Out[294]:False

np.isnan(any(test))
Out[295]:ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Here are my original lines.

```
 Eu=['Austria','Belgium','Curacao','Denmark','Finland','France','Germany']

 for country in Eu:
        for year in range(2001,2012)
            if math.isnan(all(df.loc[(df['Country Name'] == country) & (df['Years'] == year)])):
                df.loc[(df['Country Name'] == country) & (df['Years'] == year)]=df.loc[(df['Country Name'] == 'eu') & (df['Years'] == year)]
```

Thanks !

Comment: you didn't need math.isnan, pandas has many way to detect NAN, such as .isna, .isnull

Comment: I am a bit curious, what is your final working code? Because `df.loc[(df['Country Name'] == country) & (df['Years'] == year)]=df.loc[(df['Country Name'] == 'eu') & (df['Years'] == year)]` for me not working with sample data.

Comment: @jezrael My final code is as below:  

`df=df.set_index(['Country Name','Years'])  
for Country in Eu:  
    for year in range(2001,2016):  
        if df.loc[(Country,year), : ].isnull().values.all():   
             df.loc[(Country,year), : ]=imp.loc[('European Union',year),:]   
imp=imp.reset_index()`  

Honestly, the two FOR loops seem redundent. (Sorry I have some trouble in the line breaking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
df.isnull().values.any()
```

For your case:

```
test.isnull().values.any()
```

Comment: hmmm,, it is more complicated, but if it working good for OP, then ok

Answer (score 3):

If need convert only NaNs rows:

```
print (df)
    Country Name  Years  tariff1_1  tariff1_2  tariff1_3
830      Hungary   2004   9.540313   6.287314  13.098201
831      Hungary   2005        NaN   6.281724  13.124401
832      Hungary   2006        NaN        NaN        NaN
833      Hungary   2007        NaN        NaN        NaN
834           eu   2005   8.550000   5.700000  11.400000
835           eu   2006   8.460000   5.900000  11.600000
836           eu   2007   8.560000   5.300000  11.900000
```

---

```
Eu=['Austria','Belgium','Curacao','Denmark','Finland','France','Germany','Hungary']

#all columns without specified in list
cols = df.columns.difference(['Country Name','Years'])
#eu DataFrame for repalce missing rows
eu = df[df['Country Name'] == 'eu'].drop('Country Name', 1).set_index('Years')
print (eu)
       tariff1_1  tariff1_2  tariff1_3
Years                                 
2005        8.55        5.7       11.4
2006        8.46        5.9       11.6
2007        8.56        5.3       11.9

#filter only Eu countries and all missing values with columns cols 
mask = df['Country Name'].isin(Eu) & df[cols].isnull().all(axis=1)

#for filtered rows replace missing rows by fillna 
df.loc[mask, cols] = pd.DataFrame(df[mask].set_index('Years')
                                          .drop('Country Name', 1).fillna(eu).values,
                                  index=df.index[mask], columns=cols)
print (df)
    Country Name  Years  tariff1_1  tariff1_2  tariff1_3
830      Hungary   2004   9.540313   6.287314  13.098201
831      Hungary   2005        NaN   6.281724  13.124401
832      Hungary   2006   8.460000   5.900000  11.600000
833      Hungary   2007   8.560000   5.300000  11.900000
834           eu   2005   8.550000   5.700000  11.400000
835           eu   2006   8.460000   5.900000  11.600000
836           eu   2007   8.560000   5.300000  11.900000
```

Comment: Thank you and this is truly helpful !! I use 'set_index(['Country Name','Years'])' and  '.isnull().values.all()' to select, but also with two for loops layers,seem too redundent. Learned a lot from your post :)

Comment: @ZhouXing98 - Super, glad can help! Check carefully your data, because I think your solution is wrong.

Comment: @jezael Yes I have checked the result , no big problems here. Thanks still for the advice !! :D

Comment: @ZhouXing98 - Then super, I was worried about wrong output. Nice day!